# notation for space of probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, notation

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F})$ be a measurable space. Let $\mathscr{P}$ be the space of all valid probability measures on this space. Clearly, $\mathscr{P} \subset [0,1]^\mathscr{F}$. I was wondering if there exists a standard notation for $\mathscr{P}$, i.e., using $\mathscr{F} $ and/or $\Omega$.

Please note that [Space of probability measures "complete"? (In the other sense)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291515/space-of-probability-measures-complete-in-the-other-sense) does not answer my question.

Comment: No idea why this was closed as a duplicate.  The linked question does not answer this question at all, though it is somewhat related.

Comment: It will depend on $\Omega$ and $\mathscr{F}$ for sure. I don't think there is any universal notation for such an object, but I could be wrong.  When $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^d$, and $\mathscr{F}$ is the Borel sigma algebra (usually implicitly assumed) its typical to write $\mathscr{P}=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, I guess you already know this though xd